# How to transfer large file (File size > Heap Size) over the network?

Tags: java, data-structures

How to transfer large file (File size > Heap/RAM Size) over the network ?

Lets say I have file (size 10GB) I want to transfer it machine a (RAM 512mb) to machine b 
 (RAM 512mb).

Want achieve this using java code.

First, is it possible ? Any recommendation on framework. If possible, can we speed this up using threading ? Important criteria: file's data sequence needs to be maintained during transfer. Any example will be great help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure it is possible. You just have to use streams. If threading will improve transfer speed depends on your network, I would say you can't gain an improvement because you are implementing the sender and the receiver (and you won't limit the bandwidth). So the limiting factor will be the network bandwidth which you can't extend. But you can consider compressing your stream.

An example is hard to give without knowing your requirements. We are using [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) for example to transfer a file by RMI. But I wouldn't recommend doing this if you are not forced to use RMI.

Comment: I'm using JavaFX along with RMIIO to send a file, but the interface is being  blocked if I've a "big" file, like a video. Do you have any suggestions to improve this? I've tried to run the code in a different thread, but it doesn't seem to work anyway.

Comment: The UI surely freezes because you do the transfer on the UI thread. Maybe your thread implementation was wrong. I wouldn't blame this on RMIIO. If you can't fix the thread you might want to open a new question and post a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) with your code.

Comment: Here you have my just asked question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36471224/how-to-send-a-big-file-using-rmiio-when-using-javafx-without-freezing-the-ui

Answer (score 1):

> First, is it possible ?

You read and write a block at a time e.g. a `byte[]` of 8 KB.

> Any recommendation on framework. If possible, can we speed this up using threading ?

You can speed this up by increasing the amount of bandwidth you have. Its highly unlikely that CPU is your bottleneck so its unlikely threading will make it faster (but it will make your code more complicated)

> Any example will be great help.

There are millions on the web already. ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. m currently looking for one of those millions. :) Can you point me to the reliable solution/URL?

Comment: The best solution usually depends on what you are doing, but the core is pretty basic. If you are not sure I would use `IOUtils.copy` You can look at its source to see how its done.

Comment: ha, i had to re-read the first sentence 5 times... "you read and write a _bit_ at a time".

Comment: @jtahlborn I have clarified it with `block`.  I used `bit` in the more generic sense. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use streaming transfer. This means you read data into a buffer of fixed size, say 64 kB, then send the data in the buffer, then read another buffer-full of data and so on. This way you need a constant amount of memory regardless of the file's size (it could even be infinite and you would keep transferring it without even using up too much memory). Check out [`InputStream`'s methods which read bytes into an array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) or `SocketChannel` from `nio` which uses `ByteBuffers`.

Answer (score 1):

> First, is it possible ?

Of course.

> Any recommendation on framework.

No framework.  You just read a buffer / write a buffer until it is all finished.

> If possible, can we speed this up using threading ?

Using one thread to read from the local and another to write to the network socket is unlikely to help.  In most cases, you can read the file tens or hundreds of times faster than you can write it to the network, so there is little scope for speedup by double buffering.

Under some circumstances you can get more throughput by performing the transfer using multiple parallel streams.  However, this can also cause network congestion, and that can lead to reduced throughput.  And of course, you risk hurting network performance for other users.

So my advice would be not to bother trying to speed up transfers by multi-threading unless it is a critical issue and you can afford to spend lots of time on the problem.